# Tinymce integration

Tags: tinymce

I want to use TinyMCE for text editing. My folder structure is like...

`|------- css <-- here I keep all the css files of my website.`

`|------- js <-- here I keep all the javascripts of my website.`

`|------- img <-- here I keep all the images of my website.`

`|------- index.php <-- It is my index page in website root`

`|------- admin`

`|-------|------- index.php <-- It is my admin folder`

My problem is when I am using TinyMCE in my admin/index.php to edit some articles and insert an image the path is being saved in the database is ../img/someimage.jpg where index.php in my root folder could not displaying the image as the path should be img/someimage.jpg.

**What should I do ?**

Answer (score 1):

You might want to include images in the editor using classes and css (have a look at the tinymce config parameter content_css for styling elements).
otherwise you need to make sure that the image elements in your editor are accessible from all over the network where your editor content will be accessible.